# css верстка макета

Tags: html, css3

как разместить блоки, что под слайдером, так же, как на картинке, с помощью flexbox?

[image]

Comment: Как говорится, хочешь помочь, дай человеку удочку а не рыбу, вот игра для изучения модели флексбокс - http://flexboxfroggy.com

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не флексбокс, конечно, но существует хорошая JavaScript библиотека (Masonry) для создания различных макетов сетки: http://masonry.desandro.com/ .

А вот пример реализации под Ваши нужды:
http://codepen.io/bzvyagintsev/pen/adRjEM

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 * { box-sizing: border-box; }
    /* ---- grid ---- */
    .grid {
      background: #EEE;
      max-width: 1200px;
    }
    /* clearfix */
    .grid:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      clear: both;
    }
    /* ---- grid-item ---- */
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
      width: 20%;
    }
    .grid-item {
      height: 100px;
      float: left;
      background: #D26;
      border: 2px solid #333;
      border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .grid-item--width2 { width:  40%; }
    .grid-item--height2 { height: 200px; }
```

JS

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  percentPosition: true
});
```